# Nagios doesn't Trigger Continuous Alerts

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I have setup Nagios on one of my VM.
I receive the first alert when a service is Critical. But I do not receive the subsequent alert/email.

```
Host template config
define host {
       name                                 host-template
       alias                                Default server template
       check_command                        check_dummy!0!!!!!!!
       max_check_attempts                   10
       check_interval                       5
       retry_interval                       1
       check_period                         24x7
       event_handler                        notify-host-by-email
       event_handler_enabled                1
       process_perf_data                    1
       contacts                             user1
       notification_interval                10
       notification_period                  24x7
       first_notification_delay             0
       notification_options                 d,u,s,
       notifications_enabled                1
       _LTERM_LOAD_C                        10
       _LTERM_LOAD_W                        5
       _USED_MEM_C                          30
       _USED_MEM_W                          20
       _USED_SPACE_C                        40
       _USED_SPACE_W                        30
       register                             0
}

Host config:
define host {
    host_name           aaaaa
    use                 bbbbb
    alias               DEV
    display_name        DEV
    address             11.111.111.111
    _KEY                xx
    _SERVERPORT         xx:8082
    _SERVERPORTLFAT     xx:443
    _URL                xx:8082
    _USER               test01
    register            1
}
```

`notification_interval` is enabled but still i don't see any notifications.
I'm unsure if there is anything that is overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

```
max_check_attempts                   10
```

Nagios will try 10 more times before send you notification. Try to comment it and check again

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out that the service template had some notification configuration setup on it and it was overriding the settings present in host template.
Hence correcting it resolved my issue.